# Regex with gsub and grepl in R: finding ',' not followed by a space

Tags: r, regex, gsub, grepl

I want to find any element on a vector that has a **',' not followed by a space**.

I found in different sources:

- that \b  or \s  stand for white space
- \S is everything but white space
- [^] should be everything but

**Why will these not produce the expected result?** given that the /S is everything but a space and ^\s should mean the same...

```
grepl(',[^\b]', c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,')) # output: FALSE  TRUE FALSE expected: TRUE FALSE TRUE
gsub(',[^\b]', 'here', c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,')) # output: "a,"    "bhere" "c,"   expected: "ahere"    "b" "chere"
gsub(',[^\\s]', 'here', c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,')) # output: "a,"    "bhere" "c," expected: "ahere"    "b" "chere"
gsub(',[^\\S]', 'here', c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,')) # output: "a,"    "bhere" "c,"   expected: "a,"    "bhere" "c,"
gsub(',(\\S)', 'here', c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,')) # output: "a,"  "b, " "c," expected: "ahere"    "b" "chere"
```

This is not homework, this is a minimal working example.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Edited the code section to include the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated solution**
This could be used too if you wanna replace the matching parts:

- Here we only have one capturing group which is `[^0-9]` that matches a non-digit character and `(?!\\s)` is not considered a capturing group
- Then we use back references to keep our capturing group `\\1` and paste it with `here` as replacement

```
gsub("([^0-9]),(?!\\s)", "\\1here", c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,'), perl = TRUE)

[1] "ahere" "b, "   "chere"
```

This could help:

- `.` matches every character then we followed it up with a literal `,` in a capturing group
- `(?!...)` is the negative lookahead meaning not followed by `...` so we replace `...` with `\\s` as we don't like our capturing group characters to be followed by a white space
- `gregexpr` or `regexpr` returns a list of indices giving the beginning or ending position of idices where matches happen
- We then use `regmatches` to extract the matching elements

```
vec <- c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,')
unlist(regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(.,)(?!\\s)", vec, perl = TRUE)))
or
#Filter(length, regmatches(vec, gregexpr("(.,)(?!\\s)", vec, perl = TRUE)))

[[1]]
[1] "a,"

[[2]]
[1] "c,"
```

Or this one:

```
regmatches(vec, regexpr("(.,)(?!\\s)", vec, perl = TRUE))

[1] "a," "c,"
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use `"(.*?,)"` instead of `"(.,)"`. So you are able to extract "abc," and `*?` is a non greedy matching. Try it with "abc,def," and "(.*,)" vs "(.*?,)". :-)

Comment: When we only have 1 character, does it really matter to use `(.,)` or `(.*?,)`? because here `.` only matches one character but `.*` matches everything.

Comment: You are right, but I always try to generalize a solution. ;-)

Comment: As you use perl=TRUE, then the base R regex as no use (as I used in my example)? Or maybe the question should be where do I find the correct guide for regex in R?

Comment: @Sapiens I didn't understand, would you please let me know if my solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
grepl(",(?!\\s)", c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,'), perl = TRUE)
gsub(",(?!\\s)", "here", c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,'), perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you give some explanation?

Comment: I think we also have to remove `, ` anyway for the non-matching element but not sure if there is a mistake from the op or that has to be applied to. In that case we need a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Why your expressions fail?**

- `,[^\b]`: a comma and any character different from backslash and `b`
- `,[^\s]`: a comma and any character different from backslash and `s`
- `,[^\S]`: a comma and any character different from backslash and `S`
- `,(\S)`: a comma and any character different from whitespace.

When you omit `perl=TRUE` expressions may act weird in R functions.

Use

```r
gsub(',(?! )', '', x, perl=TRUE)
grepl(',(?! )', c('a,', 'b, ', 'c,'), perl=TRUE)
```

Without `perl=TRUE` lookaheads like `(?! )` won't work.

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Great explanation :)